How can I write delete test method for delete action in ASP.NET Core?
I want to write test method for delete action, but I don't know how
and I would like the delete test method to be similar to Detail test method (code logic and syntax):
// GET: ProductController/Delete/5
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    return View();
}

// POST: ProductController/Delete/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
              return BadRequest(ModelState);

          _productService.Remove(id);

          return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}

//--------
public void Remove(long Id)
{
    var product = _context.Products.Find(Id);

    if (product == null)
        _context.Products.Remove(product);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}

I would like the delete test method to be similar to detail test method, that is I want to have 2 AAA section (AAA for Arrange, Act, Assert), one section for checking Valid Id and second section for checking Invalid Id
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, -1)]
public void Detail_Test(int validId, int invalidId)
{
    // Arrange
    var moqData = new MoqData();

    var moq = new Mock<IProductService>();
    moq.Setup(p => p.GetById(validId)).Returns(moqData.GetData().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == validId));

    ProductController productController = new ProductController(moq.Object);

    // Act
    var validResult = productController.Details(validId);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(validResult);

    var validViewResult = validResult as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Product>(validViewResult.ViewData.Model);

    ///------------------------------------------

    // Arrange
    moq.Setup(p => p.GetById(invalidId)).Returns(moqData.GetData().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == invalidId));

    // Act
    var invalidResult = productController.Details(invalidId);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(invalidResult);
}


Hi Zahra, please check my test code if it useful to you ?
